DBT - pulling column comments on DBT views from another process that populates information_schema.columns
I have a couple of curated views on Snowflake that are re-created via dbt a couple of times each day via DBT. For the columns existing in these views, I have a separate process on Snowflake which runs and updates the column definitions inside information_schema.columns from a source table that is maintained elsewhere inside the database. However, every time a dbt build runs, it wipes off these column definitions from the views, since they are being managed outside of dbt, and hence it does not have any knowledge of them.
I am looking for a way to not overwrite these column definitions every time dbt does a create or replace view command. I’ve tried a couple of options so far:

Set the columns: false inside the persist_docs setting within the dbt_project.yml file (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/persist_docs). However, it did not work, and the column definitions do get overwritten each time a dbt build is run.

I can execute a post-hook to run my Snowflake stored procedure which updates the column definitions after the dbt jobs run, but I’m not sure if I should call it at the very end of the dbt runs, or individually inside the models where my views are defined.


Please share if anyone has run into a similar issue.
Thanks much!

What exactly are you updating in information_schema.columns? Most of what you would want to control in that table can be done through the model definition in your schema.yml and enabling persist_docs (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/persist_docs). Everything else should be read-only.
